# compare subset of 2d array and string array

Tags: android, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have been working on this problem for about five hours, implementing many different ways to achieve this goal, but nothing seems to be working. I am at the point to where I can't even think straight any more, so I am posting this here.

I have a shared preference which retrieves a string. that string is converted into a string array. I have a 2d array with four arrays set to the index. I want to loop through the 2d array and compare my string array to it. If the contents of each 2d array index are found in my string array, print true, else, false.

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = CocktailsFrag.this.getActivity().getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
//recall stored ingredients
String arrayString = sharedPref.getString("myIngredients", null);

if(arrayString ==null) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    String str1 = arrayString.replace("[", "");
    String str2 = str1.replace("]", "");
    String[] strValues = str2.split(",");

    String drink1[] = {"Ale", "Brandy"};
    String drink2[] = {"Vodka", "Tobasco Sauce"};
    String drink3[] = {"Lager", "Stout"};
    String drink4[] = {"Guiness", "Champagne"};
    String[][] arrays = {drink1, drink2, drink3, drink4};

    for(int i=0; i<arrays.length-1;i++) {
        String[] indexValue = arrays[i];
        if(strValues[i].contains(indexValue[i])) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), indexValue[i]+ "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: To clarify do the contents of the `String[]` from the preferences need to match the values in all arrays in the 2d array or just one array within the 2d array?

Comment: No, just one of the arrays. If one of the 2d arrays is found within the shared preference array, I want it to print true. If it is not (i.e. missing a value) then it prints false. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I added one answer using Lists instead of arrays and another option that uses just the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not as efficient as simply iterating over the arrays but it doesn't matter with the number of elements and it is easier to read.

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPref = CocktailsFrag.this.getActivity().getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
//recall stored ingredients
String arrayString = sharedPref.getString("myIngredients", null);

if(arrayString ==null) {
    //do nothing
} else {
    String str1 = arrayString.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    List<String> strValues2 = Arrays.asList(str1.split(","));

    String drink1[] = {"Ale", "Brandy"};
    String drink2[] = {"Vodka", "Tobasco Sauce"};
    String drink3[] = {"Lager", "Stout"};
    String drink4[] = {"Guiness", "Champagne"};
    String[][] arrays = {drink1, drink2, drink3, drink4};

    for(String[] drinkArr : arrays){
        if(strValues2.containsAll(Arrays.asList(drinkArr))) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to do this using arrays only one option is the following.

```
for(String[] drinkArr : arrays) {
    boolean allDrinksFound = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < drinkArr.length; i++) {
        boolean drinkFound = false; 
        for(int j = 0; j < strValues.length; j++) {
            if(drinkArr[i].equals(strValues[j])) {
                drinkFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        allDrinksFound = allDrinksFound && drinkFound;
    }

    if(allDrinksFound) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You have given me some great input and it most definitely points me in the right direction! :)